# black screen with the dock appearing just a few instants

Tags: display

I'm using a MacBookPro (13 inch, Mid 2010) with a graphic card NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MN.

Elementary OS Juno starts and goes to a black screen with the dock appearing just a few instants.

With the tty terminal I tried to modify GRUB as suggested is several posts, but without results.

What about changing the driver of the graphic card and in which way?

Best, Pietro

Answer (score 1):

A first auto-answer.
To disable Nouveau driver follow https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Now Elementary starts with the graphic page.

Nest step, I guess, is to install the correct graphic driver for the hw.